# "[fail] Can't find file: config/schedule.rb" rails, whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rubygems, whenever

I got this message -> "[fail] Can't find file: config/schedule.rb"

I'm using "whenever" gem -> https://github.com/javan/whenever

I did put it in my Gemfile

```
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

then
    wheneverize .

& I have file in config/schedule.rb with

```
every 2.hours do
  rake "thinking_sphinx:index"
end
```

When I run -> "whenever" or "whenever --update-crontab mycron --set environment=development" or "whenever --update-crontab mycron"
I get this msg -> "[fail] Can't find file: config/schedule.rb"

Thank you.

Comment: are you in the rails directory when you ran `whenever`?

Comment: Thank you very much :)
I was in the config folder:)
Maybe you can post it as an answer & I'll vote. It was so easy :)

Comment: hehe someone posted it as an answer. too bad for me.  i'll still add it anyway. it's up to you to mark it as an answer or not :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you're probably not in the rails root directory so going to the root path should fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with?

```
cd /my_rails_application_root_path && bundle exec whenever
```

You can check the binary source code at https://github.com/cwninja/whenever/blob/master/bin/whenever

If you don't pass the attribute -f, it will use config/schedule.rb by default, but you can also run

```
whenever -f COMPLETE_PATH_TO_SCHEDULE_RB
```

Comment: Thank you for the help :)
The answer is in the comment :)